# Text extraction without loosing the text format

Tags: file, text, pdftotext

Hei,

I'm currently studying text extractors softwares, like `pdftotext`, `antiword`, `catdoc`, etc... & i would like to understand why there isn't softwares that maintain the text perfect. Is it so difficult parse the text without losing the formatting?

Thanks.

Comment: At least partly, if not mainly, because there is no standard way of representing "formatted text".  Each file format has their own way of doing things, not all of which can be handled by (all) the others.  There are utilities that will convert from one format to another, but there will often be things that could be done in one format that couldn't be done in another.

Comment: HM.. in theory, is it possible to create parsers for each file to a standard way?

Comment: In theory one might, but the "standard way" would be a complete new format in itself, which would, necessarily, be at least as complex as all of the formats you were trying to convert from (since to be accurate and all encompassing, it would need to support ALL the features of ALL the formats you were targeting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it so difficult parse the text without losing the formatting?

Yes!

> i would like to understand why there isn't softwares that maintain the text perfect

If you really start thinking about solving this problem, you will quickly understand why this is difficult to do. Typically what happens is people look at their computer screen and just see a bunch of text drawn on it and don't understand the difference between what is on the screen and what is stored in a file.

As some of the comments on the question indicate, each file format has its own unique challenges, I am more familiar with PDF than other file formats though so let's take a simplified look at that.

PDF was built to be a page description language, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format), something a computer can interpret and draw on the screen that looked like the author intended no matter where it was viewed.

This means that what is stored in the PDF is the minimal amount of information for the computer to be able to reproduce the visual representation and nothing more. A number of PDF creation tools support just as much as they have to, other creation tools provide more information about the content of the PDF so that extracting content later is possible without needing to OCR the PDF.

There are multiple ways that text can be stored in a PDF, actual text, images that include text, or paths. There are probably more than that as well and of the 3 I listed, only 1 is what we would think of as being **real text**, except from the end users perspective they are all text because that is what they see, they don't see how that text got drawn onto the screen and this doesn't even begin to talk about different languages, encodings, and fonts.